# Subdomains on LAN?

Tags: dns, lan, subdomain

I have a Ubuntu Server 12.10 with Apache acting as web server.

I have to ping it in the way DEV01.local because DEV01 alone wouldn't resolve.

I would like to have a subdomain, like redmine.DEV01.local.

I have a modem/router that I got from my ISP and doesn't have DNS I think, it has DHCP.

In order to get DEV01.local ping working I had to install in both Ubuntu PC's the AVAHI-DAEMON.

Is it possible to add the subdomain in the server without having to add it manually to all LAN PC hosts file?

Comment: Where do your PCs look for DNS?

Comment: @Tanner Hi, my modem/router has Google's DNS setted up. I think my network pc's use Netbios because of Avahi.

Comment: Avahi is only for Zeroconf and mDNS, Netbios is a Windows-specific term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is doable - but not straight forward (ie it requires a good grasp of  DNS, DHCP and routing - all these are complementary components - DHCP does not replace DNS)

To implement it:

- Change the IP address on your server to a static IP address. (You should
  really do this even if you run DHCP as it is a server)
- Temporarily change the IP address on your workstation to a static IP
  address (assuming your workstation is not a server)
- Ensure that you have a default route out through your router.

  You might need to temporarily change the DNS settings on your machines to
  8.8.8.8 (or another nameserver. 8.8.8.8 is Googles and is easy to remember)
- Install and configure DNSMasq to handle DHCP and DNS. There are guides
  on the Internet.  A simple one is - 
  http://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/dnsmasq
- You will probably need to add your desired host name into /etc/hosts
  on the server running DNSMasq (DNSMasq can read the /etc/hosts and
  add it to the DNS - you might need to tweek the settings to make it work
  exactly how you want it to, but an "out-the-box" install should 
  more-or-less work)
- Disable DHCP on your router.
- Change your workstation back to using DHCP.

Comment: Thanks I think I'll have to try it, I'm installing now. Is there a way to auto-register the domain? I mean, do not edit DNS Server's host file but being client say "Hey, I have this subdomain too, can you register it?"

Comment: I suspect there is, but I've never played around with it.  I suspect it will involve changes to WINS and also running SAMBA (for WINS server), and doing netbios/windows sharing -> dns translations.  I don't do Windows though, so maybe you need to ask that as another question !

Answer (score 0):

To use subdomains you'll need to point DNS to a server on your local network. This means setting up a DNS server on your network. You'll want to configure a forward lookup zone for DEV01.local, a CNAME record for any subdomains, and a forwarder to 8.8.8.8 for Internet.